# Explain the statement

Tags: random

I meet the following statement in a code. Can somebody explain it to me, please?
My problem is mostly with the number 0.80. Where do we get it? I know that Math.random generates numbers between 0-0.99.

```
if (Math.random() > 0.80) { ... }
```

Comment: It's probably an attempt at getting a 20% probability..

Comment: 0.80 is just an arbitrary value used in a comparison. Without a contaxt it's impossible to say why it's been used.

Comment: If it is arbitrary value, then can I change it for example to 0.50?

Comment: @user3266734 the 0.80 is just a magic number they are using to determine how often they want the if statement to be entered.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand! Thank you for all! (I am just a beginner in java.)

Comment: @user3266734 If you change it to 0.5, then the `{...}` clause will be invoked, on average, 50% of the time rather than 20%.  For a uniform(0,1) value, the probability of being above 0.8 is 0.2.  It would have been cleaner/clearer had they specified `Math.random() <= p`, because that has probability `p` of evaluating to `true`, so it gives a direct and readable value of what proportion of the time the bracketed code will be invoked.

Answer (score -1):

They are trying to create a `if` statement that gets executed randomly about 20% of the time.

the 0.80 is just a 'magic number' for their particular application. For example changing it from 0.80 to 0.50 would result in the `if` statement getting executed about 50% of the time.